# storage-attach id different from the vagrant customisation id

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant

I am using vagrant and ubuntu16.04 .

When i ran vagrant up i got the error as

```
A customization command failed:

["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "IDE Controller", "--port", 1, "--device", 0, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "server.vdi"]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["storageattach", "538c4e03-f4ea-4adf-af6e-02d303d56f13", "--storagectl", "IDE Controller", "--port", "1", "--device", "0", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "server.vdi"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Could not find a controller named 'IDE Controller'
>

Please fix this customization and try again.
```

There seems to be conflict between the id generated by script and virtualbox machines one.

My Vagrant file is

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
server_disk='server.vdi'
desktop_disk='desktop.vdi'
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.box = "centos/7"
 config.vm.define "classroom" do |s|
  s.vbguest.auto_update = false
  s.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.254"
  s.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  #s.vm.synced_folder "../repos", "/repos", owner: "root", group: "root"
  s.vm.synced_folder "scripts/classroom", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  s.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/classroom.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/classroom.sh
  SHELL
 end

 config.vm.define "server" do |a|
  a.vbguest.auto_update = false
  a.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   unless File.exist?(server_disk)
    v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', server_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
   end
   v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', server_disk]
   end
  a.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
  a.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  a.vm.synced_folder "scripts/server", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  a.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/server.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/server.sh
  SHELL
  end

 config.vm.define "desktop" do |b|
  b.vbguest.auto_update = false
  b.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   unless File.exist?(desktop_disk)
    v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', desktop_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
   end
   v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', desktop_disk]
   end
  b.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  b.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  b.vm.synced_folder "scripts/desktop", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  b.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/desktop.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/desktop.sh
  SHELL
  end
end
```

VBoxManage list vms
gives output as
"ubuntu-server" {bc38335e-ddf7-48a1-b0be-3df2495b91df}

Comment: On changing the IDECONTROLLER to IDE the issue was fixe

Answer (score 0):

On changing the IDECONTROLLER to IDE the issue was fixed